# How does 'slot activator' work in vuetify?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I am using Vuetify predefined Template 'Google Contacts'.

Link: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/examples/layouts/googleContacts

I am new in Vuetify and facing difficulties understanding some codes. One is **'slot activator'**.

Sample Code:

```html
    <v-list-tile slot="activator">
        <v-list-tile-content>
            <v-list-tile-title>
                {{ item.text }}
            </v-list-tile-title>
        </v-list-tile-content>
    </v-list-tile>
```

Can anybody tell me how 'slot activator' works?

Answer (score 50):

When you declare a Vue component, you can create [**Named Slots**](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Named-Slots), which is a **Vue *native*** feature (not from Vuetify):

> For example, suppose we have an `app-layout` component with the
> following template:
>
> ```html
> <div class="container">
>   <header>
>     <slot name="header"></slot>
>   </header>
>   <main>
>     <slot></slot>
>   </main>
>   <footer>
>     <slot name="footer"></slot>
>   </footer>
> </div>
> ```
>
> Parent markup:
>
> ```html
> <app-layout>
>   <h1 slot="header">Here might be a page title</h1>
>
>   <p>A paragraph for the main content.</p>
>   <p>And another one.</p>
>
>   <p slot="footer">Here's some contact info</p>
> </app-layout>
> ```
>
> The rendered result will be:
>
> ```html
> <div class="container">
>   <header>
>     <h1>Here might be a page title</h1>
>   </header>
>   <main>
>     <p>A paragraph for the main content.</p>
>     <p>And another one.</p>
>   </main>
>   <footer>
>     <p>Here's some contact info</p>
>   </footer>
> </div>
> ```

Notice the `<slot name="header"></slot>` in the example template declaration (first code block above). When someone uses that component, she can declare `<h1 slot="header">Here might be a page title</h1>` and this code will take `<slot name="header"></slot>`'s place in the final markup.

Here's a demo of the `<slot>`s in action:

```js
Vue.component('mycomponent', {
  template: "#mycomponenttemplate"
})
new Vue({
  el: '#app'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.13/dist/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <app-layout>
    <h1 slot="header">Here might be a page title</h1>

    <p>A paragraph for the main content.</p>
    <p>And another one.</p>

    <p slot="footer">Here's some contact info</p>
  </app-layout>
</div>

<template id="mycomponenttemplate">
    <div class="container">
      <header>
        <slot name="header"></slot>
      </header>
      <main>
        <slot></slot>
      </main>
      <footer>
        <slot name="footer"></slot>
      </footer>
    </div>
</template>
```

## Your code

You show [the example](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetifyjs.com/blob/master/examples/layouts/googleContacts.vue#L26-L35):

```
<v-list-group
         ...
          >
            <v-list-tile slot="activator">
              ...
            </v-list-tile>
```

As you can see, this code tries to place the `v-list-tile` in the `activator` **slot** of the parent component (`v-list-group`).

Having a look at [the official docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/lists#api) (incl. [the old version](https://vuetifyjs.com/releases/0.17/#/components/lists#api)), there's no mention if the `<v-list-group>` has a slot named `activator`.

But a look at **[`<v-list-group>`'s SOURCE CODE](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/42cf784714c3309f04eaf09a79494d16c68e9d5a/src/components/VList/VListGroup.js#L134)** quickly proves there does exist one.

Comment: Very nice Explanation! Thanks. Can you provide me any link to easy Tutorials on Vue or Vuetify?

Comment: @Md.HarunOrRashid  I couldn't find any documentation directly related to the term `activator`.

Comment: Read the end of the answer. The name of the slot is anything. They called it `activator` because they wanted to. Check their code: https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/42cf784714c3309f04eaf09a79494d16c68e9d5a/src/components/VList/VListGroup.js#L134  Could have been anything else and it would work the same.