# v-dialog not showing upon clicking the v-btn inside v-data-tables

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm new to vuejs and I'm using vuetify.I just want to show a dialog upon clicking the button inside the v-data-table. This is what I have done so far.

```
https://codepen.io/iskaryote1/pen/GbYjZJ?&editable=true&editors=101
```

**v-dialog**

```
<v-dialog v-model="dialog" persistent max-width="290">
          <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
            <v-btn color="primary" dark v-on="on">Open Dialog</v-btn>
          </template>
          <v-card>
            <v-card-title class="headline">Use Google's location service?</v-card-title>
              <v-card-text>Let Google help apps determine location. This means sending anonymous location data to Google, even when no apps are running.</v-card-text>
            <v-card-actions>
              <v-spacer></v-spacer>
              <v-btn color="green darken-1" flat @click="dialog = false">Disagree</v-btn>
              <v-btn color="green darken-1" flat @click="dialog = false">Agree</v-btn>
            </v-card-actions>
          </v-card>
        </v-dialog>
```

everytime I click the button, my browser hangs and the console log says **too much recursion**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just put the dialog modal outside the table and open it programmatically with a simple button:

```js
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-data-table
      :headers="headers"
      :items="desserts"
      class="elevation-1">
      <template v-slot:items="props">
        <td>{{ props.item.name }}</td>
        <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.calories }}</td>
        <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.fat }}</td>
        <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.carbs }}</td>
        <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.protein }}</td>
        <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.iron }}</td>
        <td>
          <v-btn color="primary" dark @click="dialog = true">Open Dialog</v-btn>
        </td>
      </template>
    </v-data-table>

    <v-dialog v-model="dialog" persistent max-width="290">
      <v-card>
        <v-card-title class="headline">Use Google's location service?</v-card-title>
        <v-card-text>Let Google help apps determine location. This means sending anonymous location data to Google, even when no apps are running.</v-card-text>
        <v-card-actions>
          <v-spacer></v-spacer>
          <v-btn color="green darken-1" flat @click="dialog = false">Disagree</v-btn>
          <v-btn color="green darken-1" flat @click="dialog = false">Agree</v-btn>
        </v-card-actions>
      </v-card>
    </v-dialog>    
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: It works, but do you have any idea why my the other one is not working?

Answer (score 0):

The recursion is vuetify trying to open a slot in a slot in a slot... Looks like your template slot itself is opening itself every time it opens itself.

I'd advise you to read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55188478/meaning-of-v-slotactivator-on) that gives detailed explanations on the use of `v-slot:activator`.

Comment: I also tried without the activator
    https://codepen.io/pen/?&editable=true&editors=101
but same result i get. Can you advise how can i solve this?

Comment: Your link here is empty

Comment: oops sorry. here's the link
    https://codepen.io/iskaryote1/pen/ydRVwL