# v-tooltip doesn't show component behind it

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm trying to implement [v-tooltip](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/tooltips) following the example in their documentation but I cannot make it work. If I copy the example, i receive this error:

`[Vue warn]: Property or method "on" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property.`

if I declare property `on` the btn doesn't show up at all.

This is the template:

```
<v-tooltip bottom>
     <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
        <v-btn color="primary" dark v-on="on">Bottom</v-btn>
    </template>
    <span>Bottom tooltip</span>
</v-tooltip>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49079936/how-does-slot-activator-work-in-vuetify

maybe this will help?

Comment: the activator represents the "on" as where the mouse is over the component (it can be changed to a property so it can be activated programatically).  I don't really understand why the single curly braces.

Comment: what version of vue are you using? Versions prior to 2.6 don't support `v-slot`

Comment: "vue": "^2.5.17", that might be the issue @thanksd

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're probably getting that error because the version of Vue that you're using doesn't support the `v-slot` directive, which was [added in Vue version 2.6](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/releases/tag/v2.6.0).

Either update your version of Vue, or use the slot syntax supported in prior versions:

```
<v-tooltip bottom>
  <template slot="activator" slot-scope="{ on }">
    <v-btn color="primary" dark v-on="on">Bottom</v-btn>
  </template>
  <span>Bottom tooltip</span>
</v-tooltip>
```